# get rows count from database using MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

how can I get the count of records in the table users in the applicationContextcreatedin the mvc project?

this is what I have tried so far:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var count = context.Users
.Where(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.Id) == 1)
.Count();

if (count < 3)
{

//do whatever

}
```

it's giving an error at the convert.ToInt32, and if I remove the convert it will give an error cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'int' (o.Id) == 1)

what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.Users.Count()` should work. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just compare it as a string if thats what it is?

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var count = context.Users
.Where(o => o.Id == "1")
.Count();
```